# Copying a string into a list isn't working - C#, Unity3D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a dialogue system and a journal system that should allow the player to copy dialogue lines that have just been said into their journal, however, copying the strings into the list isn't working.

I've been using `string.Copy` to copy the value of the string instead of the reference, but it doesn't copy anything over at all. Cutting `string.Copy` and copying the reference doesn't appear to work either. The line I'm copying from does have a value, I printed a `debug.log` to print the value for it before printing the value of the list items (see below)(edited to include full script).

```cs
public class JournalTester : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<DiaEntryClass> diaJournal = new List<DiaEntryClass>();

    GameObject diaSysObject;
    private DialogueSystem diaSysScript;
    string testLine = "inital value for testline";
    string testName = "Initial NPC name value";

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("k"))
        {
            Debug.Log("K");
            diaSysObject = GameObject.Find("DialogueSystem");
            diaSysScript = diaSysObject.GetComponent<DialogueSystem>();
            testLine = diaSysScript.justSaid;
            testName = diaSysScript.justSpoke;

            Debug.Log("testLine post copy: " + testLine);


            diaJournal.Add(new DiaEntryClass(string.Copy(testLine), "Bernard's Apartment", string.Copy(testName)));
            Debug.Log("Using the string.Copy method.....................................................");
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry 0, Line: " + diaJournal[0].line);
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry 0, Character: " + diaJournal[0].character);
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry 0, Location: " + diaJournal[0].location);

            diaJournal.Add(new DiaEntryClass(testLine, "Bernard's Apartment", testName));
            Debug.Log("Not using the string.Copy method..................................................");
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry 1, Line: " + diaJournal[1].line);
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry 1, Character: " + diaJournal[1].character);
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry 1, Location: " + diaJournal[1].location);
        }
      }
    }


public class DiaEntryClass
{
    public string line;
    public string location;
    public string character;

    public DiaEntryClass (string line, string location, string character)
    {
        line = "initial line";
        location = "initial location";
        character = "character";
    }
}
```

Above is the custom class I'm using for dialogue entries. 
But no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to work like that. Below is my `Debug.Log` lines:

> testLine post copy: Hello! My name is John Doe Using the string.Copy
>   method..................................................... Dialogue
>   Journal, Entry 0, Line:  Dialogue Journal, Entry 0, Character:
>   Dialogue Journal, Entry 0, Location:  Not using the string.Copy
>   method.................................................. Dialogue
>   Journal, Entry 1, Line:  Dialogue Journal, Entry 1, Character Dialogue
>   Journal, Entry 1, Location:

The Character string should print as "John".
The Line string should print as "Hello! My name is John Doe."
The Location string should print as "Bernard's Apartment".
So `testLine` does have the correct value, since it did successfully print the test line I was using, but that value isn't transferring over into the list and I don't know why. I couldn't find anything about `String.Copy` in the Unity Documentation, so I was worried I was using something wrong? I don't know for sure.

Comment: Care to show more of your script?  You are literally printing what is at index 0, after calling add twice, and we have no idea how many times you added it to before hand. (So in your second case you wouldnt want to print the same index since you added a new entry.)

Comment: Also I recommend adding a `debug.log(diaJournal.length)` or count which ever it is for you diaJournal type.

Comment: Also include the definition for `DiaEntryClass`

Comment: I added more of my script, but this is the only time this list is created and added to. And to be clear, I added to the same index twice specifically to test if using String.Copy to try to copy the value would work, or if not using String.Copy to copy the reference would work. It didn't work in either instance, so I felt it would be useful to leave it in case that was someone's suggestion. 
I thought that lists didn't have a set length by default, but I could be wrong. 
I included the DiaEntryClass, but it just holds three strings, nothing crazy

Comment: your `DiaEntryClass` constructor isn't actually setting the values to what you passed in.  So that is 1 issue.

Comment: You didnt add to the same index, you added to the same list.  which means your list has more then 1 index to it, index 0 would be the first item added, index 1 would be the second item you add.  you called add, nowhere is there a remove in your script.

Comment: Make your list public, and when you are running look at it in the inspector.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I edited the the debug to print at index 0 and index 1, but unfortunately nothing copies over still. Original post has been edited to reflect it

I made the list public, but it doesn't even show up in the inspector. I thought all public variables showed up in the inspector (when playing and not when playing), so this is weird, but I could be missing something

Comment: The code you shared shows your list is private.  Make your DiaEntryClass serializable to view it in the inspector.

Comment: but you still have the issue where you aren't actually assigning your values in your constructor.

Comment: I do see that the values aren't being set in the constructor... Do I need to attach the class script to the same gameobject that the JournalTester script is on?

Comment: You shouldn't use [`string.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.copy) **at all** .. it is **legacy** coming from a time where `string` was a reference type... Nowadays every `string` assignment equals a copy .. rather simply pass in the according `string` itself.

Answer (score 2):

I made a few updates to your script I hope you can look at these changes and try using them to figure out the issue going on with your script,  btw both of the copy and non-copy methods work for me:

**Changes to your DiaEntryClass**

```
[System.Serializable] // Makes it so you can view this classes data members in the inspector, so you should see your public list now.
public class DiaEntryClass
{
    public string line;
    public string location;
    public string character;

    public DiaEntryClass(string inLine, string inLocation, string inCharacter)
    {
        // Actually setting my variables to the values passed in...
        line = inLine;
        location = inLocation;
        character = inCharacter;
    }
}
```

**Changes to your update**

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Using GetKeyDown so it runs only once, GetKey runs for every frame the key is held
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
    {
        Debug.Log("K");
        diaSysObject = GameObject.Find("DialogueSystem");
        diaSysScript = diaSysObject.GetComponent<DialogueSystem>();
        testLine = diaSysScript.justSaid;
        testName = diaSysScript.justSpoke;
        Debug.Log("testLine post copy: " + testLine);

        diaJournal.Add(new DiaEntryClass(string.Copy(testLine), "Bernard's Apartment + copy Method", string.Copy(testName)));
        diaJournal.Add(new DiaEntryClass(testLine, "Bernard's Apartment + non-copy method", testName));

        int index = 0;
        // Foreach to just loop through every entry
        foreach (DiaEntryClass dec in diaJournal)
        {
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry " + index + ", Line: " + dec.line);
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry " + index + ", Character: " + dec.character);
            Debug.Log("Dialogue Journal, Entry " + index + ", Location: " + dec.location);

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me!! Thank you so much for being patient and walking me through this, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @TaylorBazhaw, `diaSysObject = GameObject.Find("DialogueSystem"); diaSysScript = diaSysObject.GetComponent<DialogueSystem>();` should be replaced by a cached instance assigned in the inspector or found with `FindObjectOfType<DialogueSystem>()` in `Start()`. --- Reasons: Find by object name/tag is bad because of magic-string. And dependency-management should be avoided in `Update()` and other repeating methods. Error-prone and performance-critical, respectively. --- Also, if Eddge's answer helped you, upvote it, and if you feel it's the right answer to your question, mark it as accepted.

Comment: You shouldn't use [`string.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.copy) **at all** .. it is **legacy** coming from a time where `string` was a reference type... Nowadays every `string` assignment equals a copy and using `stromg.Copy` even fails in some cases .. rather simply pass in the according `string` itself.

Comment: @derHugo I didn't even know that thanks I learned something new! tbh, I had never even seen string.copy used before.  TaylorBazhaw both of what derHugo, and XenoRo have suggested are excellent points to follow.